# C# .net 4 dependency

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a standalone tool developed in C# Visual Studio Express 2010.
My problem is that this tool will fail to start on machines having no .NET installed, and asking for .NET 4 on machines has .NET under 3.5 or lower. 
What I basically want to do is to install .NET 4 from my application before the main script runs. I can write a program to download it from an official webpage, also to run the installer etc. But the main problem still exists, the app won't even reach the download part as it won't run on machines...
I've googled around and found that you can include dll-s etc., but I still doubt I can proceed without a proper .NET installation. So how can run dotnetfx.exe with my .NET dependent application?
Your attention and ideas are much appreciated.
Cs.

Comment: Most commercial applications don't install per-requisites for you.  They simply list these things as requirements.

Comment: Do you actually need .net4? Just building it in an earlier framework would take a lot of work off your hands. You also need to think about whether your tool offeres so much value, your customers would be happy with installing .net4.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Why use an earlier version of .NET Framework when this problem is easily solved by having his installer, install the version of the .NET Framework that is required, before his program is actually installed.

Comment: Easily? If they haven't got .Net4 already, there's a reason. Like XPSP3 and dial up maybe. I was thinking about it from a customer poinbt of view. As soon as you do, easy turns out to have never entered the building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - it takes care of dependencies when configured correctly and comes integrated/free with VS.

Comment: Beware of how ClickOnce applications are both deployed, and how they reside on the user's machine.  It's not your typical installer.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: So vs express editions don't support setup projects. Plan B: [wix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wix/).

Comment: Setup projects aren't available in Visual Studio Express

Comment: @shf301 - No, but 3rd party is available.

Answer (score 0):

simple. your installer must not be a .net application. just write your own c++ version or use some existing application. here is a link to show you how to do silent installs of .net 4. just include the setup application with your program. I would be very surprised if some of the msi installer tools out there do not have .net installation support.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/04/16/9553804.aspx

Comment: This answer makes no sense.  Why would he write his own program to do this?  When alternatives already exists that are both free and paid?  Visual Studio Express does not have the ability to do Setup Projects

Comment: I am not being an ass, I am pointing  out, this answer doesn't apply to the author.  Its not clear what you mean by "write your own C++ version" means exactly.

Comment: maybe it is not clear to you. why don't you let the author decide for himself what is helpful or not? or, perhaps instead of criticizing others you could try to help the author yourself? just because you don't see something doesn't mean others don't.

Comment: the author asked, "So how can run dotnetfx.exe with my .NET dependent application?" the answer is by writing a c++ application to bootstrap it because c++ does not require .net...does that make sense?

Comment: No, writting a C++ bootstrap is not clear.  There are both free and paid applications that can be set to create an installer that will install the .NET Framework if its not already installed.  I don't need to publish my own answer because, this already has been suggested, and thus doesn't need to be suggested again.

Comment: perhaps he doesn't want to use that type of installer? there are just so many variables to programming. maybe I should have called you a hound instead of a leech. lol